# EXTEND_ESLINT guidance from Fluent UI documentation causes error

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I got the following error when I run the **npm start** command:

> 'EXTEND_ESLINT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file

I followed the Fluent UI documentation regarding React Integration guidance for configuring create-react-app found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/integrations/react#configure-create-react-app). I am trying to creating a FluentUI Tab in my app and am able to get everything working without including **EXTEND_ESLINT=true** in package.json so I am wondering if this guidance regarding **EXTEND_ESLINT=true** is still necessary. I was able to follow the guidance regarding overriding the eslintConfig field to turn off the 'no-unused-expressions' rule without any problems so it was just the **EXTEND_ESLINT=true** that was problematic for me.

Here's my context:

I created a React Typescript app using this command:

> npx create-react-app app --template typescript

and then ran the following recommended npm package installation from guidance doc:

> npm install --save @fluentui/web-components @microsoft/fast-foundation
> @microsoft/fast-element @microsoft/fast-react-wrapper

Here's my environment:

npm version: 8.11.0
vscode: 1.17